# What is a vector?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

What is a vector?

As the question says what is a vector and what are its uses or, I mean, when should we use vectors?

Is this a branch of geometry or algebra or trigonometry?

Comment: It is a broad concept, but at first it is best to think of it as a combination of a direction and a magnitude. So a car's velocity is a vector, because it has a direction (the direction it is headed) and a magnitude (the speed.)

Comment: Polynomials may be vectors and functions too. I don't think that magnitude and direction really fits the characteristic of a vector

Comment: @DominicMichaelis As I said, it is a broad concept, but when you first encounter them, it is best to think of them geometrically. Yes, as he advances, he can see them as otherwise, but the way vectors first arose was in Euclidean geometry and Newtonian physics.

Comment: Note that in general, a vector is an element of a vector space. And vector spaces can be many things. But in your case, I believe you think of the vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. In this case, a vector is a set of real coordinates.

Comment: @julien But again, that is circular. I don't think OP is looking for a rigorous definition, but rather guidance, intuition, and usages.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, which is why your answer is great. But it does not necessarily hurt to hear that the notion comes from a more general setting.

Comment: Not comes from, went to..

Answer (score 2):

The basic geometric vectors are measurements which have a non-negative magnitude and a geometric direction, with the caveat that we treat all vectors with zero magnitude as the same (the zero vector.)

The most obvious example is, given two point, $A$ and $B$ in (Euclidean) space:  what direction would I have to travel to get from $A$ to $B$ in a straight line, and how far would I have to travel?

Other examples are things like the velocity of an object, or the object's momentum.

Vectors are interesting because we can "add" them (when the units are the same, as with all quantities.) If we take the "travelling" vector above, then if we travel in the direction of vector $v$ for the distance equal to the magnitude of $v$, and then travel in the direction of $w$ for the distance of $w$, we get a new vector $v+w$.  It turns out that $v+w=w+v$, which is convenient.

(Momentum is interesting, because if two objects collide and combine, one with momentum $v$ and the other with momentum $w$, it turns out the new object will have momentum $v+w$. So it is not necessary to think of vector addition as necessarily "follow one vector then the other" - rather, it is a combination. Even if the objects don't combine, but rather, glance off each other, we still have a nice property. If A had momentum $v_1$ before they collided and $v_2$ after, and $B$ had momentum $w_1$ before and $w_2$ after, it turns out, by "conservation of momentum," that $v_1+w_1=v_2+w_2$.)

You can also scale a vector by a constant, so if $r$ is any positive number, you create a vector $rv$ which is the same direction as $v$ buth with the magnitude equal to the magnitude of $v$ times $r$. There is also a notion of $-v$, which is the vector with the opposite direction to $v$ and the same magnitude, and $v+(-v)=0$, the zero vector.

These are the first types of vectors that you encounter, but the field of linear algebra introduces whole new, more abstract notions of vectors that are also quite useful. Essentially, mathematicians noticed a lot of cases where you had a collection of "vectors" $V$ and a "field of numbers" $F$ where you can add any two vectors, and you can scale any vector by any element of $F$. There are some properties required on addition and scalar multiplication to make this a vector space.  In these cases, the vectors in the vector space  might not be viewable as "direction and distance."  There is no notion of the angle between two vectors, either. We still think of these general vector spaces as essentially "geometric," but in a far more abstract way.

Answer (score 2):

First: what is a vector?

Given a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) $V$ over for example the [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) $\mathbb{R}$. Say that the dimension of the vector space is $n$. Then a vector is a $n$-tuple of numbers. For example if $n = 2$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, then 
$$
(1,2)\quad\quad (0,0)\quad\quad (-2,7)
$$
are examples of vectors.

Now this almost makes is sound like a vector is just a point, and in a certain sense it is just a point. However, where we can't technically add points, we can add vectors. We add two vectors by adding their coordinates. For example
$$
(1,2) + (-2,7) = (1 + (-2) , 2 + 7) = (-1, 9).
$$
We can also for example multiply a vector by a real number, and we do that by multiplying each coordinate by that number. Examples:
$$
3(2,7) = (3\cdot2, 3\cdot 7) = (6, 21)\\
0(2,7) = (0\cdot 2, 0\cdot 7) = (0,0).
$$
To get a complete understanding of what a vector is, you might want to look up the [definition of a vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) space because the *axioms* of a vector space is exactly what describes what you can do with vectors.

The above then is just one description of a vector. There are other ways to define them.

Second: Maybe you real question is how we should *think* about a vector. From the above you can think about a vector, for example $(2,7)$ as an arrow that starts at the origin of a coordinate system and ends at the *point* $(2,7)$. That way we can think about a vector as

- a direction
- and a magnitude (being the length of the arrow)

That being said, of you start at any other point and you draw an arrow with the same direction and magnitude, then the two arrows are the same when considered *representatives* of the vector.

Third: What are vectors good for? Vectors are very helpful in many situations. One example is when you consider a physical object with a [force working on it](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=force%20as%20vectors). By that I mean for example a football that is pulled towards Earth by the force of gravity. The (sum of the) forces that work on an object determine how the object moves. And it turns out that vectors are very helpful in thinking/working with forces. So a force is indeed something that has a direction (i.e. something being pulled in a certain direction) and a magnitude (i.e. how hard is the thing being pulled).

Answer (score 1):

A vector is an element of an Vectorspace. It's a branch of linear algebra, there is a lot to tell about vectors, where did you met a vector?

Well a vector can be nearly anything, for example every element of a field is a vector. You can use vectors to describe positions, if you take an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$  $(x,y,z)^T$ you are able to describe a position by telling it coordinates.

Comment: Of course, vectors existed before linear algebra was formulated. Linear algebra is an abstraction defined precisely to deal with ideas of vectors, so it is sort of circular to reference vector space, especially in a soft question asking for motivation.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure he even knows what a field is. Do you want to explain to a person who does not know what a field is what a vector is? He's not asking for anything formal, he's asking for intuition, usage, and guidance.

Comment: This is like Wikipedia. The intro of vectorspace says it is something that contains vectors, and the intro of vectors says it is something that is within a vectorspace. Agree with Thomas. Completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

Another kind of motivation, which was given eg by Richard Feynman (Lectures on Physics) for a vector in three real dimensions is that a vector is a set of three numbers which transforms in a certain way under rotations. The formula for the rotation of a vector is compatible with the (supposed) Euclidean geometry of space, and this compatibility is such that it enables us to write the equations of physics in a manner independent of arbitrary translations and rotations (the choice of a basis).

So, continues Feynman, if we can write a physical law in vector form we know that it is compatible with the basic conservation and invariance principles of physics.

So in a sense vectors are the natural language for Newtonian physics in three dimensional Euclidean space.

And from that starting point the right way of writing General Relativity in non-Euclidean space-time grows.

And in another development pure mathematicians discovered uses for abstract vector spaces (eg in describing extensions of fields) which go beyond the physical ideas of magnitude and direction.